# Psycopg2 syntax error when using SQL module

Tags: python, postgresql

```
query=SQL(
    "CREATE USER {id} WITH PASSWORD %s".format(
        id=Identifier(id)
    )
)
try:
    self.cur.execute(
        query=query,
        vars=[password]
    )
except DuplicateObject:
    print("{id} User already created.".format(id=id))
else:
    print("{id} User create.".format(id=id))
```

This is the code to create a user in postgresql.

```
query=SQL(
    "CREATE USER {id} WITH PASSWORD %s".format(
        id=Identifier(id)
    )
)
```

ID argument is defined as identifier class.

```
self.cur.execute(
            query=query,
            vars=[password]
        )
```

The password argument is defined as a variable of the execution function.

> psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: 오류:  구문 오류, "(" 부근
> LINE 1: CREATE USER Identifier('administrator') WITH PASSWORD 'Y2zfW...

When I run the code, I get a syntax error.
Why am I getting a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the wrong `.format`.  This works for me:

```
query = sql.SQL("CREATE USER {} WITH PASSWORD %s").format(sql.Identifier('falken'));
c.execute(query, ['pencils'])
```

Notice that I am calling `.format` on the SQL object, not on the string!

Comment: you're right.
thank you.